# Sorting behavior specification in order by for window function in GBQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I am running a query in GBQ using window function. but I don't exactly know how to specify sorting behavior. In order by column I have two columns which I want to sort rows by them in descending order. for that I used DESC at the end of order by clause but what I got is that it orders the rows first on ascending order for the first column and then descending on the second. my question is if I should specify sorting order for each column ?

here is the query which returns wrong order:

```
SELECT partitionDate,
      createdUTC,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY externalid ORDER BY partitionDate, createdUTC DESC NULLS LAST)
```

the other query:

```
SELECT partitionDate,
          createdUTC,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY externalid ORDER BY partitionDate DESC, createdUTC DESC NULLS LAST)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting order should be specified on per column basis with ASC being default, so can be omitted. So, Yes - you should use DESC for each column as in below

```
SELECT partitionDate,
  createdUTC,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY externalid ORDER BY partitionDate DESC, createdUTC DESC NULLS LAST)
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, Is there a same rule for aggregate functions? how did you find the answer?

Comment: Yes. True universally. Just very basic fact :o)